# ASP.NET MVC: Path.Combine is producing 2 results, causing an exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

This is how I am creatinga a temporary file

```
string myFilePath = Path.Combine(tempFileLocation, myFileName);
nh.SaveToFile(myFilePath);

return myFileName;
```

I'm returning just the file name because I don't want to display the path. But later, if the user decides to download the file, I'm trying to access the file this way:

```
string myFilePath = Path.Combine(tempFileLocation, myFileName);
FileStream fs = System.IO.File.OpenRead(myFilePath);
```

I'm getting an exception: **Could not find a part of the path.**

And when I compare both strings, this is what I see:

```
C:\\TempFolder\\myFile.xls

C:\TempFolder\myFile.xls
```

Why am I getting two different strings while using the same method?

Also, I don't know whether this information will help. The first time, I'm using Path.Combine inside a c# class helper. However, the second, I'm using it inside a controller.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: please include what nh is. and where you are getting the two strings that you're comparing. Clearly they're not both directly from `Path.Combine()`. Or if they are both from `Path.Combine` directly, then also include how `tempFileLocation` is retrieved in both Actions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will fix your issue but you can try doing it without Path.Combine.

Like this:

```csh
        string myFilePath = tempFileLocation.ToString() + 
        System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + myFileName.ToString();

        FileStream fs = System.IO.File.OpenRead(myFilePath);
```

Comment: `System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar` is still adding only one backslash, which still causes the exception.

Comment: If your using two different functions, you could just add more separators :) You would have to break up the other strings though to add in the others...